# Comparing the Most Significant Bit of two numbers: ==, <, <=

Tags: bit-manipulation

Is there a quick bit operation to implement `msb_equal`: a function to check if two numbers have the same most significant bit?

For example, `0b000100` and `0b000111` both have 4 as their most significant bit value, so they are most `msb_equal`. In contrast `0b001111` has 8 as the MSB value, and `0b010000` has 16 as it's MSB value, so the pair are *not* `msb_equal`.

Similarly, are there fast ways to compute <, and <=?

Examples:

```
msb_equal(0, 0) => true
msb_equal(2, 3) => true

msb_equal(0, 1) => false
msb_equal(1, 2) => false
msb_equal(3, 4) => false

msb_equal(128, 255) => true
```

---

A comment asks why 0 and 1 are not msb_equal. My view on this is that if I write out two numbers in binary, they are msb_equal when the most significant 1 bit in each is the same bit.

Writing out 2 & 3:

```
2 == b0010
3 == b0011
```

In this case, the top most 1 is the same in each number

Writing out 1 & 0:

```
1 == b0001
0 == b0000
```

Here, the top most 1s are not the same.

It could be said that as 0 has no top most set bit, `msb_equal(0,0)` is ambiguous. I'm defining it as `true`: I feel this is helpful and consistent.

Comment: why does `msb_equal(0, 1) => false`? Their msb's are 0 unless you count only 1-bit numbers

Comment: OK I get what you mean, but only because of the answer. Can you clarify it in the question?

Comment: msb typically refers to the most significant bit in a "word", not the highest 1 bit. So the title is a bit misleading. Because if it's the normal msb then you just need to `return !((a^b) & 0x80000000)` to check for msb equality of 32-bit ints

Comment: :-) I'd describe that usage as "frequently" what is referred to, rather than "typically". I hope the modified title is clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are fast bit based operations to compute MSB equality and inequalities.

## Note on syntax

I'll provide implementations using c language syntax for bitwise and logical operators:

- `|` – bitwise OR. `||` – logical OR.
- `&` – bitwise AND. `&&` – logical AND.
- `^` – bitwise XOR.

## `==`

```
msb_equal(l, r) -> bool
{
  return (l^r) <= (l&r)
}
```

## `<`

This is taken from the Wikipedia page on the [Z Order Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) (which is *awesome*):

```
msb_less_than(l, r) -> bool
{
  (l < r) && (l < l^r)
}
```

## `<=`

```
msb_less_than_equal(l, r) -> bool
{
  (l < r) || (l^r <= l&r)
}
```

Comment: Can I use similar function for a size-L prefix instead only one  bit?  See [details here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2891840/70274)

Comment: @PeterKrauss I don't think the equality / inequalities given here help with the problem that you link to, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which number is the smallest/biggest one, there is a very fast way to check whether the MSBs are equal. The following code is written in C:

```
bool msb_equal(unsigned small, unsigned big) {
    assert(small <= big);
    return (small ^ big) <= small;
}
```

This can be useful in cases like when you add numbers to a variable and you want to know when you reached a new power of 2.

**Explanation**

The trick here is that if the two numbers have the same most significant bit, it will disappear since 1 xor 1 is 0; that makes the xor result smaller than both numbers. If they have different most significant bits, the biggest number's MSB will remain because the smallest number has a 0 in that place and therefore the xor result will be bigger than the smallest number.

When both input numbers are 0, the xor result will be 0 and the function will return true. If you want 0 and 0 to count as having different MSBs then you can replace `<=` with `<`.